# Swift - Game crashes after launchScreen and cannot transition to GameScene NSException Error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was trying to redo my LaunchScreen.storyboard so I deleted it and created a new LaunchScreen via File(in the toolbar) > New > New File > Launch Screen and then I started getting this problem. I've already checked my IBOutlet connections. I deleted the new LaunchScreen.storyboard in hopes of solving it but it still can't transition to my GameScene. I use SpriteKit and UICollectionView for my game.

[Debug Navigator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QbH8.png)

[AppDelegate SIGABRT Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiH51.png)

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) e Thread.callStackSymbols.forEach{print($0)}

0   ???                                 0x00000001062343cc 0x0 + 4397941708
1   Billionaire City                    0x00000001006e23b8 main + 0
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00000001c28f7ea8 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00000001c1fc4788 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00000001c1fc4934 <redacted> + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001c1fdbe00 <redacted> + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00000001c1fd0838 <redacted> + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00000001c1fd01a8 __cxa_get_exception_ptr + 0
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00000001c1fd0168 <redacted> + 0
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001c1fdbb3c <redacted> + 0
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001c2d1d278 <redacted> + 0
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001c2e05d60 <redacted> + 1408
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001c2e079fc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
13  CoreText                            0x00000001c6a178d0 <redacted> + 92
14  UIFoundation                        0x00000001cd3edf78 <redacted> + 120
15  CoreText                            0x00000001c6a1707c <redacted> + 84
16  CoreText                            0x00000001c6a169d0 <redacted> + 92
17  CoreText                            0x00000001c6a16834 <redacted> + 104
18  CoreText                            0x00000001c69c660c <redacted> + 216
19  CoreText                            0x00000001c69c651c <redacted> + 160
20  CoreText                            0x00000001c69c1da4 CTTypesetterCreateWithAttributedString + 60
21  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d98f1c04 _ZN12SKCLabelNode11rebuildTextEv + 1064
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001019f8c74 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101a07480 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 124
24  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d98f1230 _ZN12SKCLabelNode21addRenderableChildrenEP13SKCRenderInfoPNSt3__16vectorIP7SKCNodeNS2_9allocatorIS5_EEEE + 92
25  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d99aed90 _ZN11SKCRenderer18doBuildRenderGroupEP7SKCNode14SKCRenderState13simd_float4x4 + 372
26  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d99aefb8 _ZN11SKCRenderer18doBuildRenderGroupEP7SKCNode14SKCRenderState13simd_float4x4 + 924
27  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d99aefb8 _ZN11SKCRenderer18doBuildRenderGroupEP7SKCNode14SKCRenderState13simd_float4x4 + 924
28  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d99ae2fc _ZN11SKCRenderer16buildRenderGroupERKNSt3__110shared_ptrI18SKCRenderSortGroupEE + 940
29  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d99ab608 _ZN11SKCRenderer15buildRenderPassERKNSt3__110shared_ptrI13SKCRenderPassEE + 96
30  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d99aaea0 _ZN11SKCRenderer6renderEP7SKCNodeDv4_fRKNSt3__110shared_ptrI15jet_framebufferEEDv4_j13simd_float4x4bP12NSDictionaryP8SKCStatsSE_d + 1628
31  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d9928c80 <redacted> + 664
32  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d9928958 <redacted> + 252
33  SpriteKit                           0x00000001d992cbec <redacted> + 184
34  UIKitCore                           0x00000001ef7cbe54 <redacted> + 1292
35  QuartzCore                          0x00000001c728e1f0 <redacted> + 184
36  QuartzCore                          0x00000001c7293198 <redacted> + 332
37  QuartzCore                          0x00000001c71f60a8 <redacted> + 348
38  QuartzCore                          0x00000001c7224108 <redacted> + 640
39  UIKitCore                           0x00000001ef35c534 <redacted> + 124
40  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001c2d9210c <redacted> + 20
41  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001c2d91a10 <redacted> + 272
42  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001c2d8ca74 <redacted> + 1024
43  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001c2d8c354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
44  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001c4f8c79c GSEventRunModal + 104
45  UIKitCore                           0x00000001ef343b68 UIApplicationMain + 212
46  Billionaire City                    0x00000001006e2404 main + 76
47  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001c28528e0 <redacted> + 4
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable for an application to run with a `LaunchScreen`.

In order to fix your problem, try adding a new `LaunchScreen`, then head to `Project Settings - General` and from the `Launch Screen File` drop down menu select your new `LaunchScreen`.

[image: LaunchScreen drop down Menu]

You can also run it without a `LaunchScreen`. Delete the `LaunchScreen` from project in `Xcode` and `Finder`, then head to `Project Settings - General` and from the `Launch Screen File` drop down menu select `scene-name (Main)`.